# Sencha Touch animation options

Tags: animation, sencha-touch-2

Where can I find a list of the available animation types for Ext.Panel.show()?  I've searched the documentation and googled "sencha touch animation options", but can't find anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can see all the animations here

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/production/kitchensink/

And here's the API

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.anims

Answer (score 1):

Here is the documentation for the available animation types:

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.anims

Some of them don't work on Android.

Answer (score 1):

In ST 2

- cube *
- fade
- flip *
- pop
- slide
- wipe *

*does not work in android

```
Ext.Anim.run(this, 'fade', {
  out: false,
  autoClear: true  
});
```

Do not forget the

```
Ext.requires('Ext.Anim');
```