# Partial closing animation effect in Ext.tab.Panel

Tags: extjs, web

I would like to know how to create [this animation effect](http://screencast.com/t/H5cVcYzOxhDt) in Ext.tab.Panel.

Comment: Try to refer this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9670028/sencha-touch-animation-options

Comment: What about using [this example](http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/examples/admin-dashboard/#dashboard) but with a mouseover event instead of click.

Comment: @MichelFRANKE is there any way to see the source code? I know i can get it via F12 and within app.js but that is really chaotic. Thanks for reply

Comment: I think the examples are included in the extjs sdk. So even if you downloaded the GPL version, you allready should have the examples.